# How to check if a process is running or blocked on lock or I/O?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line-interface, perl, blocking

There are 2 instances of a script reported by `ps`.
How can I see in the command line if one of those (and which) is blocked on either I/O or on a file lock?

Answer (score 0):

When you execute ps -aux, in the column STAT, you can see the process state codes.

Taken from man ps:

> PROCESS STATE CODES
> Here are the different values that the s, stat and state output specifiers (header "STAT" or "S") will display to describe
> the state of a process:
>
> ```
>            D    uninterruptible sleep (usually IO)
>            I    Idle kernel thread
>            R    running or runnable (on run queue)
>            S    interruptible sleep (waiting for an event to complete)
>            T    stopped by job control signal
>            t    stopped by debugger during the tracing
>            W    paging (not valid since the 2.6.xx kernel)
>            X    dead (should never be seen)
>            Z    defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent
>
>    For BSD formats and when the stat keyword is used, additional characters may be displayed:
>
>            <    high-priority (not nice to other users)
>            N    low-priority (nice to other users)
>            L    has pages locked into memory (for real-time and custom IO)
>            s    is a session leader
>            l    is multi-threaded (using CLONE_THREAD, like NPTL pthreads do)
>            +    is in the foreground process group
> ```